# Server Manager Remote Connection and Visual Studio unable to publish after password change

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, visual-studio, windows

I have a developer user who changed his password in our Windows-only environment.  Now he is unable to connect remotely to another machine via Server Manager and unable to publish to another server via Visual Studio.

There are no event logs or failed security audits and I've tried restarting the requisite services, removing and re-adding his membership in certain permission groups both locally and in AD, and restarting the box but still no luck.

Does anybody have any idea what might be happening and how to fix?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the resolution, somehow this user had an entry in credentials manager.  Once that was removed they were able to publish and remote with server manager without issue.